# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'users' from dj-rest-auth

Tags: python-3.x, django, dj-rest-auth

I am trying to run celery on a Django application that has dj-rest-auth already configured but, I get the following error when I run - "celery -A config worker -l info" but, it works perfectly fine without errors when I do "python manage.py runserver".

The application has several apps under the folder /apps and within the settings.py, it is imported as "apps.<app_name>". It does have an app called "users" so, it's imported as "apps.users".

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/celery", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 15, in main
    sys.exit(_main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 213, in main
    return celery(auto_envvar_prefix="CELERY")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 26, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 134, in caller
    return f(ctx, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 343, in worker
    worker = app.Worker(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.app.loader.init_worker()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 111, in init_worker
    self.import_default_modules()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 105, in import_default_modules
    raise response
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/utils/dispatch/signal.py", line 276, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py", line 82, in on_import_modules
    self.worker_fixup.validate_models()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py", line 121, in validate_models
    run_checks()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 412, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 598, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 591, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/config/urls.py", line 13, in <module>
    path("api/v1/auth/", include("dj_rest_auth.urls")),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dj_rest_auth/urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    from dj_rest_auth.views import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dj_rest_auth/views.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .app_settings import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dj_rest_auth/app_settings.py", line 35, in <module>
    UserDetailsSerializer = import_callable(serializers.get('USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER', DefaultUserDetailsSerializer))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dj_rest_auth/utils.py", line 12, in import_callable
    return getattr(import_module(package), attr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'users'
root@1a45d3d56ced:/app# celery -A config worker -l info
DEBUG 2021-12-09 11:36:44,651 base 132 140186677212992 Configuring Raven for host: None
INFO 2021-12-09 11:36:44,652 base 132 140186677212992 Raven is not configured (logging is disabled). Please see the documentation for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/celery", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 15, in main
    sys.exit(_main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 213, in main
    return celery(auto_envvar_prefix="CELERY")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 26, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 134, in caller
    return f(ctx, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/bin/worker.py", line 343, in worker
    worker = app.Worker(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/worker/worker.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.app.loader.init_worker()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 111, in init_worker
    self.import_default_modules()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/loaders/base.py", line 105, in import_default_modules
    raise response
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/utils/dispatch/signal.py", line 276, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py", line 82, in on_import_modules
    self.worker_fixup.validate_models()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/fixups/django.py", line 121, in validate_models
    run_checks()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 412, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 598, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 591, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/config/urls.py", line 13, in <module>
    path("api/v1/auth/", include("dj_rest_auth.urls")),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dj_rest_auth/urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    from dj_rest_auth.views import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dj_rest_auth/views.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .app_settings import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dj_rest_auth/app_settings.py", line 35, in <module>
    UserDetailsSerializer = import_callable(serializers.get('USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER', DefaultUserDetailsSerializer))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dj_rest_auth/utils.py", line 12, in import_callable
    return getattr(import_module(package), attr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'users'
```

Comment: Just curious, have you found the answer? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same problem. The imports in this case include the module specification strings from `settings.py`, not just the `import` statements at the top of the modules. In our case this was the fix

```
 
 REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
-    "LOGIN_SERIALIZER": "users.api.serializers.LoginSerializer",
+    "LOGIN_SERIALIZER": "<app_name>.users.api.serializers.LoginSerializer",
 }
```